# Where to find the read data after a bio in the Linux kernel?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, block-device

I'm trying to make my own device mapper, which first maps the bio (read) request onto another one. However, after completion of the remapped request, I want to access the data that was read. I've been looking at the important data structures, and see no field members that would contain the read data (eg. [struct bio](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/blk_types.h#L237), [bio_vec](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/bvec.h#L32), [bvec_iter](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/bvec.h#L38), etc.)

I feel lost cause it would seem like such a straightforward thing to do, and yet I can't find it.

Comment: `struct bio_vec  *bi_io_vec; /* the actual vec list */`  Each vec is a page and a range of data on the page.

Comment: Note that you never actually access the vecs directly.  Use the macros.

Comment: @stark Thanks, this contains the page, but I'm still a bit lost which macros to use to get the actual data read?

Comment: Chapter 16 of ldd3. https://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/